# how to slow down translation

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, translate

I have a translation for my object which i believe will make my object move around in a spherical area(may be wrong).

```
    gl.glTranslatef(mTransX,mTransY, -10.0f);

    float max = 360.0f;
    float min = -360.0f;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    mTransX = rnd.nextFloat()*(max-min)+min;
    mTransY = rnd.nextFloat()*(max-min)+min;
```

This is in the ondraw method but the object moves around the screen too quickly. It will flash by too fast to really see it, so i was wondering if there was a way to control the speed.

Comment: Calculate a new random number less frequently

Comment: Use smaller min/max values